# How to compile expat with iOS SDK 5.1?

Tags: cross-compiling, ios5.1, expat-parser

How to compile expat with iOS SDK 5.1? I tried to adapt/upgrade from all older scripts, but nothing worked... Could anybody do it already?

Comment: Now llvm-cpp-4.2 compiler is missing in Xcode 5.0 on Mavericks, I suppose. Expat is not building anymore. The file config.log says: "line 1582: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2: No such file or directory" Any hints on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

I used the following script:
https://github.com/x2on/expat-ios

The problem is that the command "xcode-select -print-path", used in the compilation script, is showing "/Developer" instead of the correct full path including "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer". I just changed it and then it worked!

The last XCode [SDK 5.1] moved the path of the developer tools and SDK to inside the XCode bundle.

Comment: Could you get it to build successfully? I am getting some error, all it says is: "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 77"

Comment: yes, it worked for me. I just fixed the line 'DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`' to the correct XCode path

Comment: Could you also compile it for the iOS device? Coz when I try to compile it for the ARM, it gives out error 77 which indicates "C compiler cannot create executables" but the iOS simulator (i386) does not complain though. Curious about how you have done it. Did you modify anything in the shell script? Thanks!

Comment: I don't work on this since 2012, but this was my last script that used to build it. maybe you gotta change a little bit nowadays: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1me869mc8dyr48/build_ios.sh

Comment: Thanks for the update, looks like there are a lot of changes with the new OS and Xcode update. Please see my question, you may also face this problem if you are building with the latest SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813065/compiling-expat-for-ios-7-sdk-xcode-5-mavericks

Answer (score 1):

When trying to compile for iOS6.1 with the developer tools accompanying XCode 4.6.3, the script at https://github.com/x2on/expat-ios stops after building the iOSSimulator library. The iOSDevice version does not build. It seems the newer developer tools do not support armv6.

Removing armv6 from `ARCHS="i386 armv6 armv7"` will build the library at least for armv7.