# Compiling expat for iOS - Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 77

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, build, compilation, cross-compiling

I am trying to import the [libkml library](https://github.com/gumdal/libkml-pointinpolygon) into my iOS project. I realised that expat libraries cannot be linked (?) and so have to build the expat sources for it again.

I found a SO link where a gentleman mentions that he could successfully link expat with his iOS SDK 5.1: [How to compile expat with iOS SDK 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453946/how-to-compile-expat-with-ios-sdk-5-1)

I tried the same using the [script available in github](https://github.com/x2on/expat-ios) as mentioned in the above link.

But, I am getting an error in the Run phase of the script. I could not make the most out of it but I need help to fix this.

The script used is the same as from github link. C++ standard library in the project is set to "Compiler default" which I presume is LLVM C++. Below is the output from config.log which I am not able to make out with my level of understanding. Please help me out in resolving this problem and build the library to link it across with my project:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by expat configure 2.0.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/raj/Projects/test/bin/iPhoneSimulator5.0-i386.sdk --host=i386-apple-darwin --enable-static

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Rajs-MacBook-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.3.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 100 tasks, 561 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 2.90, Mach factor: 5.09
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2092: checking build system type
configure:2110: result: i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:2118: checking host system type
configure:2132: result: i386-apple-darwin
configure:2148: checking for i386-apple-darwin-gcc
configure:2174: result: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
configure:2456: checking for C compiler version
configure:2459: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --version </dev/null >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2462: $? = 0
configure:2464: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configure:2467: $? = 0
configure:2469: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -V </dev/null >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2472: $? = 1
configure:2495: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2498: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include  -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/raj/Projects/test/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2501: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "expat"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "expat"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "expat 2.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "expat-bugs@libexpat.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2540: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
ac_cv_build_alias=i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include'
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/raj/Projects/test/lib'
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=i386-apple-darwin
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i386-apple-darwin
ac_cv_host_alias=i386-apple-darwin
ac_cv_prog_CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AS=''
CC='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc'
CFLAGS='-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include'
CPP='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++'
CXXCPP='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2'
CXXFLAGS='-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include'
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
ECHO='echo'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77=''
FFLAGS=''
FILEMAP=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS='-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/raj/Projects/test/lib'
LIBAGE='5'
LIBCURRENT='6'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBREVISION='2'
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='expat-bugs@libexpat.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='expat'
PACKAGE_STRING='expat 2.0.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='expat'
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.0.1'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_AS=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DLLTOOL=''
ac_ct_F77=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
ac_ct_STRIP=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-apple-darwin12.3.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i386'
build_os='darwin12.3.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${prefix}/share'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i386-apple-darwin'
host_alias='i386-apple-darwin'
host_cpu='i386'
host_os='darwin'
host_vendor='apple'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='/Users/raj/Projects/test/bin/iPhoneSimulator5.0-i386.sdk'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "expat-bugs@libexpat.org"
#define PACKAGE_NAME "expat"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "expat 2.0.1"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "expat"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.0.1"

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the errors, I was missing the C compiler. I then downloaded the Xcode command line tools then these errors could be fixed.