# Compiling expat for iOS - Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, build, compilation, cross-compiling

**PS:** [My earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594336/compiling-expat-for-ios-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-77) was different, that could be fixed, now I am running into new problem

I am trying to import the [libkml library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594336/compiling-expat-for-ios-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-77) into my iOS project. I realised that expat libraries cannot be linked (?) and so have to build the expat sources for it again.

I found a SO link where a gentleman mentions that he could successfully link expat with his iOS SDK 5.1: [How to compile expat with iOS SDK 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453946/how-to-compile-expat-with-ios-sdk-5-1)

I tried the same using the [script available in github][2] as mentioned in the above link.

But, I am getting an error in the Run phase of the script. I could not make the most out of it but I need help to fix this.

The script used is the same as from github link. C++ standard library in the project is set to "Compiler default" which I presume is LLVM C++. Below is the output from config.log which I am not able to make out with my level of understanding. Please help me out in resolving this problem and build the library to link it across with my project:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by expat configure 2.0.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/raj/Projects/test/bin/iPhoneSimulator5.0-i386.sdk --host=i386-apple-darwin --enable-static

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Rajs-MacBook-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.3.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 124 tasks, 641 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 1.70, Mach factor: 6.28
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin
PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2092: checking build system type
configure:2110: result: i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:2118: checking host system type
configure:2132: result: i386-apple-darwin
configure:2148: checking for i386-apple-darwin-gcc
configure:2174: result: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
configure:2456: checking for C compiler version
configure:2459: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --version </dev/null >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2462: $? = 0
configure:2464: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configure:2467: $? = 0
configure:2469: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -V </dev/null >&5
llvm-gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2472: $? = 1
configure:2495: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2498: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include  -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/raj/Projects/test/lib conftest.c  >&5
configure:2501: $? = 0
configure:2547: result: a.out
configure:2552: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2558: ./a.out
configure:2561: $? = 0
configure:2578: result: yes
configure:2585: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2587: result: no
configure:2590: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2592: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -o conftest -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include  -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/raj/Projects/test/lib conftest.c  >&5
configure:2595: $? = 0
configure:2620: result: 
configure:2626: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2647: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -c -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include  conftest.c >&5
configure:2650: $? = 0
configure:2672: result: o
configure:2676: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2700: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -c -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include  conftest.c >&5
configure:2706: $? = 0
configure:2710: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2713: $? = 0
configure:2716: test -s conftest.o
configure:2719: $? = 0
configure:2732: result: yes
configure:2738: checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc accepts -g
configure:2759: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:2765: $? = 0
configure:2769: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2772: $? = 0
configure:2775: test -s conftest.o
configure:2778: $? = 0
configure:2789: result: yes
configure:2806: checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc option to accept ANSI C
configure:2876: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  -c -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:10:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:11:23: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:12:22: error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
conftest.c:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'FILE'
configure:2882: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "expat"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "expat"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "expat 2.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "expat-bugs@libexpat.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdarg.h>
| #include <stdio.h>
| #include <sys/types.h>
| #include <sys/stat.h>
| /* Most of the following tests are stolen from RCS 5.7's src/conf.sh.  */
| struct buf { int x; };
| FILE * (*rcsopen) (struct buf *, struct stat *, int);
| static char *e (p, i)
|      char **p;
|      int i;
| {
|   return p[i];
| }
| static char *f (char * (*g) (char **, int), char **p, ...)
| {
|   char *s;
|   va_list v;
|   va_start (v,p);
|   s = g (p, va_arg (v,int));
|   va_end (v);
|   return s;
| }

.
.
.
.
.


configure: exit 0
```

In addition to the above config.log file, I could find a build log too.

Details of the build-expat-2.0.1.log file:

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin
checking for i386-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking dlfcn.h usability... no
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: dlfcn.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: dlfcn.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: dlfcn.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: dlfcn.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: dlfcn.h: proceeding with the preprocessor's result
configure: WARNING: dlfcn.h: in the future, the compiler will take precedence
configure: WARNING:     ## -------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to expat-bugs@libexpat.org ##
configure: WARNING:     ## -------------------------------------- ##
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for i386-apple-darwin-g++... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2
checking for i386-apple-darwin-g77... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-f77... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-xlf... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-frt... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-pgf77... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-fort77... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-fl32... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-af77... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-f90... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-xlf90... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-pgf90... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-epcf90... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-f95... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-fort... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-xlf95... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-ifc... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-efc... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-pgf95... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-lf95... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-gfortran... no
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/nm output from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for i386-apple-darwin-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for i386-apple-darwin-ranlib... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib
checking for i386-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for i386-apple-darwin-gcc... (cached) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc accepts -fexceptions... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... no
checking for memmove... no
checking for bcopy... no
checking fcntl.h usability... no
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: proceeding with the preprocessor's result
configure: WARNING: fcntl.h: in the future, the compiler will take precedence
configure: WARNING:     ## -------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to expat-bugs@libexpat.org ##
configure: WARNING:     ## -------------------------------------- ##
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) no
checking for off_t... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) no
checking for unistd.h... (cached) no
checking for getpagesize... no
checking for working mmap... no
checking for an ANSI C99-conforming __func__... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating expat_config.h
config.status: expat_config.h is unchanged
/bin/sh ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -I./lib -I. -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -I/Users/raj/Projects/test/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fexceptions  -DHAVE_EXPAT_CONFIG_H -o lib/xmlparse.lo -c lib/xmlparse.c
lib/xmlparse.c:6:65: error: string.h: No such file or directory
lib/xmlparse.c:7:20: error: assert.h: No such file or directory
In file included from lib/xmlparse.c:24:
lib/expat.h:17:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
lib/xmlparse.c:81:2: error: #error memmove does not exist on this platform, nor is a substitute available
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'parserCreate':
lib/xmlparse.c:719: warning: implicit declaration of function 'malloc'
lib/xmlparse.c:719: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'
lib/xmlparse.c:722: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
lib/xmlparse.c:723: error: 'realloc' undeclared (first use in this function)
lib/xmlparse.c:723: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
lib/xmlparse.c:723: error: for each function it appears in.)
lib/xmlparse.c:724: error: 'free' undeclared (first use in this function)
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'parserInit':
lib/xmlparse.c:848: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memset'
lib/xmlparse.c:848: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'XML_Parse':
lib/xmlparse.c:1543: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c:1543: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'XML_GetBuffer':
lib/xmlparse.c:1627: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memmove'
lib/xmlparse.c:1627: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memmove'
lib/xmlparse.c:1656: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'XML_GetParsingStatus':
lib/xmlparse.c:1750: warning: implicit declaration of function 'assert'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'storeRawNames':
lib/xmlparse.c:2009: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'doContent':
lib/xmlparse.c:2424: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memcmp'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'storeAtts':
lib/xmlparse.c:2922: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c:2931: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'addBinding':
lib/xmlparse.c:3039: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'lookup':
lib/xmlparse.c:5871: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
lib/xmlparse.c:5898: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
lib/xmlparse.c:5927: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
lib/xmlparse.c: In function 'poolGrow':
lib/xmlparse.c:6112: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
lib/xmlparse.c:6148: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
make: *** [lib/xmlparse.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: One of the reasons why this error occurred to me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8273239/260665

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1) build the library for OSX, that is run ./configure and make. If that works, construct a Xcode library project, add all the library source files, and the created congig.h etc. get this project to compile, then add the project to your app. I have done this and it's often the easiest (in the end) solution.

2) if you cannot get that to work offer a 100 to 250 bounty and someone else will do it. That's a clear benefit of building up points here - you can use them for something when you really need to!

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion, but I am trying to link it across with iOS sources, which means that the expat source code should be build across ARM. If I compile it in Mac, will I be able to link it with my iOS project?

Comment: I understand. When you configure for the Mac you will get more or less the same config.h file. You can hand tweak that if there is something odd about it. I've done this with two open source projects I support, xlslib and libxls. Its really hard to coerce the auto... stuff to get what you want - its seems every project is different and you can burn hours on it. If you can get this to build for the Mac I'll bet you can get a Xcode project compiling in about 30 minutes, and it will then build for any architecture now or in the future.